# use tsconfig path for src of Nextjs Image component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to save my `assets` folder path in `tsconfig` file and use it in `src` of **Image component** but it can not find the address!

tsconfig.js :

```
"paths": {
      "@/assets/*": ["public/assets/*"],
      "@/UIElm/*": ["components/UI-Elements/*"],
      }
```

my react code :

```
<div className={style.images}>
    <Image alt="app screenshot" src="@/assets/open-account/screenshot1.svg" fill />
</div>
```

but it doesn't work!!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
import Screenshot from "@/assets/open-account/screenshot1.svg"

<div className={style.images}>
 <Image alt="app screenshot" src={Screenshot} fill />
</div>
```